# What does "Bone location is set in local space" mean?

Tags: animation, rigging

I found this in the Relations panel of Bone Data properties:

[image]

I was looking for some documentaiton about what this means and how it is used in practice. But i found nothing substantial about this. maybe someone can shed some light on this ?

btw: i have seen the entry [How does 'local with parent' space work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9143/how-does-local-with-parent-space-work)
But it does not answer this question (for me).

Answer (score 2):

It means the bone behaves 'as normal' and location curves are based on the bone's rest position. If you uncheck it they (the curves/ transform) will be in the rotational space of the armature, ignoring the rest rotation of the bone.
Nathan added this during sintel I believe to avoid having to align bones in the rig. Honestly I think it is a nuisance.